# How to resolve hosts using Cloudera Manager 4.0 installed on EC2

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

Can anyone provide Cloudera Manager 4.1 Free Version help with instructions on resolving hosts in EC2?

I have installed Cloudera Manager 4.1 Free Version on an EC2 m1.large instance. When I search for hosts using the external host name (dn1.example.com), it comes up correctly and installs the packages correctly. But, upon inspection, it does not come up. The only server that comes up is the server where Cloudera Manager is installed (ip-#-#-#-136.ec2.internal). I even tried to use the other host names for dn1 (ec2-#-#-#-47.compute-1.amazonaws.com, ip-#-#-#-152.ec2.internal) in the host searches. Both install successfully but don't show up in inspection. I'm at a loss.

Our admin has toyed around with /etc/hosts, /etc/resolv.conf, /etc/sysconfig/network. No combinations seem to work.

If there is an expert out there who can help, please can you explain what to do?

Very grateful,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue of cloudera successfully adding a host and not showing it in the host list by following changes

1. in all the host machines(including the one having cloudera manager), add similar contents to /etc/hosts file(note, i have removed the default entry localhost.localdomain)

   127.0.0.1        localhost

   ::1              localhost6.localdomain6         localhost6

   X.X.X.X          master.cloudera.mydomain        master

   Y.Y.Y.Y          slave1.cloudera.mydomain        slave1
2. Add this extra search entry to /etc/resolv.conf(keep the default search entry as it is)

   search cloudera.mydomain

Restart system/network interface for the changes to take effect.
    /etc/rc.d/init.d/network restart

Now, try adding both the machines. it worked for me.

Source: [Cloudera Manager fails to add hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579105/cloudera-manager-fails-to-add-hosts)

Comment: Thanks. The problem was solved by our sys admin. He forgot to open the ports in iptables.