# installation failed on all hosts cloudera manager on Debian 8.4

Tags: cluster-computing, host

I tried to follow the instruction mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579105/cloudera-manager-fails-to-add-hosts/49791371#49791371) , but i still have to same problem : the hosts still unknown for CDH and the error is :

Installation failed. Failed to receive heartbeat from agent.
    Ensure that the host's hostname is configured properly.
    Ensure that port 7182 is accessible on the Cloudera Manager server (check firewall rules).
    Ensure that ports 9000 and 9001 are free on the host being added.
    Check agent logs in /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/ on the host being added (some of the logs can be found in the installation details).

By the way im using Debian 8.4 jessie distribution as operating system

Can you help me to resolve this problem please .

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can anyone help me please ?